# Revit API - How to Access Family Parameters "Discipline" and "Type of Parameter"

Tags: revit-api

i am trying to filter my list of a family parameters by their Discipline.
But i do not know how to access it.  The same goes for the "Type of Parameter" as you see in the image.

```c
List<FamilyParameter> famParm_lst = FamMngr.GetParameters().Cast<FamilyParameter>().ToList();
List<FamilyParameter> famParm_PipeSize_lst = famParm_lst.Where(fp => fp.Definition.(Discipline) == (Pipe Size)).Select();
```

Any idea on how i can check for a Discipline of a value "Pipe Size" ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I got the Discipline and the "Type of Parameter":

```
//tmpParam is  a Family Parameter
string getDateTypeId = tmpParam.Definition.GetDataType().TypeId;

string Discipline = getDateTypeId.Split(':')[0].Split('.').Last();
string TypeOfParameter = getDateTypeId.Split(':')[1].Split('-')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [FamilyParameter Class](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/6175e974-870e-7fbc-3df7-46105f937a6e.htm) → [Definition Property](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/00308c2a-5024-e7d8-5e6a-90c656ea2db9.htm)
 → [Definition Members](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/e9e4ea63-d291-2a06-6be4-b6cce810ba92.htm).

Comment: Hi Jeremy, that's where i have been looking but failed to find the "Discipline" field... would you happen to know the exact field that gives me that value?  Thanks